# Problem with MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf assembly in WPF projec

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, package

Description:

Hi, I'm facing an issue with the MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf assembly in my WPF project. Here are the details:

I installed MaterialDesignThemes by running Install-Package MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.

In the Solution Explorer, I can see MaterialDesignThemes version 4.9.0 in the packages.

In my GUI project (PL), I have the following references in the .csproj file:

```
xml
```

```bash
   
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BL\BL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DalTest\DalTest.csproj" />
      <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignThemes" Version="4.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In the main window XAML (MainWindow.xaml), I added the MaterialDesign themes:

xml

```bash
    <Window x:Class="PL.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PL"
            xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Window.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Dark" />
                    <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Window.Resources>
```

However, when I run the application, I encounter the following error:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'MaterialDesig

> I have tried rebuilding the solution and running dotnet restore, but the issue persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of .net is your WPF program based on? MaterialDesignThemes shows in the nuget package that it does not currently support .net 8.0. Also I found [Link 1](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/427) and [Link 2](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/980) which may be useful to you help.